# django static settings

Tags: django, requirejs

Всем привет.
Есть SPA на django. главная страница на базовом url. также есть страница регистрации на url 'landing/'.
Проблема в том, что когда с этой урл я хочу отрендерить статику, django отдаёт её не из static папки,а пытается вытянуть из 'landing/static/' то есть прибавляет еще текущий Url. и в итоге статику не находит.
как это поправить? может что в настройках не то у меня?
заранее спасибо за отзывчивость.

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка была в requirejs.config. baseUrl учитывает текущий url, а не папку. А сервер отдавал статику не по пути, а по url, следовательно необходимо было указать корректный url, в моём случае '../static/'.